# show D3.js table from a csv file once

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I'm a beginner with D3.js and I did a server in node and a web page in order to do a test. I compile the data in the server and I would like to show in a table in the web page. So, I found the following D3 example in the web and I try to used. So, when a test is executed, it works really well. However, when I'm doing a second test, without refreshing the web page, the data obtained is loaded two times. If I do three test, it loads three times... How it can be seen in the picture. I would like to load only the data once. For this, I tried to blank the container where is contained the table (csvTable), refresh the data matrix after to be saved in a .csv file. Nevertheless, nothing has worked it until now. I really appreciate if someone could help me.

```
function doTable(){

clearBox("csvTable");

d3.text("data/data.csv", function(data) {
            var parsedCSV = d3.csv.parseRows(data);

            var container = d3.select('#csvTable')
                .append("table")

                .selectAll("tr")
                    .data(parsedCSV).enter()
                    .append("tr")

                .selectAll("td")
                    .data(function(d) { return d; }).enter()
                    .append("td")
                    .text(function(d) { return d; });
    });
```

}

[image]

Answer (score -1):

What about enclosing the whole d3.text() function into an if statement like this:

```
if (!d3.select('#table-id)){
    d3.text("data/data.csv", function(data) {
        var parsedCSV = d3.csv.parseRows(data);

        var container = d3.select('#csvTable')
            .append("table")
            .attr('id', 'table-id')

            .selectAll("tr")
                .data(parsedCSV).enter()
                .append("tr")

            .selectAll("td")
                .data(function(d) { return d; }).enter()
                .append("td")
                .text(function(d) { return d; });
   });
}
```

I haven't tested the code but something along these lines should work.